# Invoking a delete function is not working in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

in my main.dart file I'm defining a function delete

```
      body: Column(
        children: quotes.map((quote) => QuoteCard(
          quote: quote,
          delete: () {
            setState(() {
              quotes.remove(quote);
            });
          }

        )).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          print('hello');
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the function is called in the quote_card.dart file inside a class and is passed as a parameter and clicking the text button(last widget) with on press does nothing.

```
class QuoteCard extends StatelessWidget {

  final Quote quote;
  final Function? delete;
  QuoteCard({ required this.quote, this.delete });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 0),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                quote.text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 6.0),
              Text(
                quote.author,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              TextButton.icon(
                onPressed: () => delete,
                label: Text('delete quote'),
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
              )
```

nothing is happening when I'm clicking the delete button in my flutter app, can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `TextButton` widget, the function you're passing to `onPressed` is not actually calling `delete`, it's only returning the `delete` function **itself**. You need to call the function (and check whether it is null, since it's optional), like so:

```
onPressed: () {
  if (delete != null) {
    delete();
  }
},
```

Alternatively, you can do it this way:

```
onPressed: delete,
```

As pointed out by @Lee3 in the comments, in order for this to work, you'll need to be more specific with the type of the `delete` property. It will need to be declared as:

```
final void Function()? delete;
```

The reason being that the `Function` type, by itself, is not specific enough for the compiler to check its correctness.

Comment: In order for the alternative approach to work, `delete` needs to be declared as `final void Function()? delete`.

Comment: @Lee3: Thanks, I'll make an edit to clarify that

Comment: first of all instead of ugly null check you can use this `delete?.call()`, also there is `VoidCallback` typedef from dart:ui package, that could be used instead of `Function()`